# Indexing array in php pdo insert while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, while-loop

I'm trying to insert a row into a table for each fetch from another table using a while loop. The code I currently have inserts the first users data into the database.

If the insert query is outside of the loop it will enter the last users data. It must be an issue iterating through the array. Is there a way I can index the array values for each pass of the loop?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_table" ;
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(); 
$statement->execute();

while($rows = $statement->fetch()){

    $salted = $sso_key . $companyId;
    $hash = hash('sha1',$salted,true);
    $saltedHash = substr($hash,0,16);

    $iv = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,16),16); //Generate random 16 bit string


    $user_data = array( 
      "user_id" => $rows['id'],
      "first_name" => $rows['first_name'],
      "last_name" => $rows['last_name'],
      "email" => $rows['email'],
      "position" => $rows['type']);

    $data = json_encode($user_data);
    $data = $iv . $data;

    $pad = 16 - (strlen($data) % 16);
    $data = $data . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,'','cbc','');
    mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $saltedHash, $iv);
    $encryptedData = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$data);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

    $encryptedData = base64_encode($encryptedData);

    $token = array(
        "token" => $encryptedData
    );

    $token_data = json_encode($token);

    echo "
    <br>Here is the token for ".$user_data['first_name'].", ".$user_data['last_name']."
    ".$user_data['email'] ." : 
    " . $token['token'];



    $query = "INSERT INTO another_table 
            (token ,first_name,last_name,email,position) 
            VALUES (:token, :first_name,
            :last_name, :email, :position)"; 


    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':token', $token['token']);
    $statement->bindValue(':first_name', $user_data['first_name']);
    $statement->bindValue(':last_name', $user_data['last_name']);
    $statement->bindValue(':email', $user_data['email']);
    $statement->bindValue(':position', $user_data['position']);


    $statement->execute();

}
?>
```

Comment: You can't call `$statement->fetchAll()` before calling `$statement->execute()`. And when you call `fetchAll()` it fetches all the rows, so there's nothing left for `while ($rows = $statement->fetch())` to fetch.

Comment: You have to define array above while loop.

Comment: @RavinderReddy Why does he have to do that? He's not pushing onto the array each time, he's just using it as a temporary within the loop.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the loop would only insert the first user's data.

Comment: Hes blowing out the object `$statement` inside the loop, from the first `$statement` object. Thats just gonna wreck havok.

Comment: What on Earth are you attempting to accomplish with that encryption?

Comment: @AlexHowansky that encryption is no doubt gonna spur another question ... cause I see nothing but problems rising from that :D

Comment: @AlexHowansky the encryption is used for creating a Single Sign On token.

Comment: Any security code that contains `md5(microtime())` or `rand()` should be burned immediately. (Not to mention, mcrypt hasn't been updated in ages as has been removed from PHP.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing that code to the basics, you have this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_table" ;
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(); 
$statement->execute();
while($rows = $statement->fetch()){
    // .. stuff ..
    $query = "INSERT INTO another_table 
            (token ,first_name,last_name,email,position) 
            VALUES (:token, :first_name,
            :last_name, :email, :position)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':token', $token['token']);
    $statement->bindValue(':first_name', $user_data['first_name']);
    $statement->bindValue(':last_name', $user_data['last_name']);
    $statement->bindValue(':email', $user_data['email']);
    $statement->bindValue(':position', $user_data['position']);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

See the problem yet? Ok, here is a hint to fix it:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users_table" ;
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$query = ".. prepared query here .."; // your second query used in the loop
$SECOND_statement = $db->prepare($query); // set it up
while($row = $statement->fetch()){
    // .. bindValue lines here .. 
    $SECOND_statement->execute();
}
```

Inside your while loop, you were overwriting the variable `$statement` with the insert sql. This effectively ended your while loop prematurely. Can also cause some serious unwanted and unexpected issues if that second sql was another SELECT.

Comment: Thanks you so much! stupid mistake. I changed the name of the $statement. I've actually encountered this before. Didn't even occur to me this time. Thanks again!

Comment: I think we've all done it once or fifty times. No problems!

Comment: @mickmackusa true. If his query is not changing at all in the while loop (no dynamic content), then `$OTHER_statement` can be first defined before that loop. (updated)